# Detecting Cardboard native app

Tags: android, jar, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm building a VR app launcher,
For this I'm running through the package manager of the installed apps and running the match command for "vr" in the packageName, which gives the result I need only if the developer have decided to add the word VR to his app name.

I'm wondering how will this detection can be made 100%.

The Manifest for a VR app doesn't seems to have any particular distinguished tag,
VR apps must use a specific JAR and are running CardboardActivity instead of regular Activity, but I don't know how to search for this features.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: The Android System searches all apps for an intent filter that matches the intent. When a match is found, [3] the system starts the matching activity by invoking its onCreate() method and passing it the Intent. For cardboard it is <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />

Comment: @user1621629 this should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by random user was correct:

Through the package manager one should read the intent of the application and search for the following intent : com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD

```
    Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intentToResolve.addCategory("com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD");
    intentToResolve.setPackage(appInfo.packageName);
    ResolveInfo ri = pm.resolveActivity(intentToResolve, 0);
```

the ResolveInfo is !=null if intent is Cardboard app.